# Get error with update_attributes in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading from Rails 4 to 5 I got the error like 'wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)' when calling `update_attributes`. Here is detail.

I have a model `User` and I overwrite the function `update_attributes` of ActiveRecord.

```
def update_attributes(attributes, options = {})
    if attributes[:password].blank? && attributes[:password_confirmation].blank?
      attributes.delete(:password)
      attributes.delete(:password_confirmation)
    end
    super(attributes, options)
end
```

I call `super` with 2 params. It can run in Rails 4 but It raises error on Rails 5. I read `update_attributes` of ActiveRecord It only has 1 param.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 5, [update_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) methods need to pass 1 arguments

Try `super(attributes)`

Answer (score 0):

`update_attributes` is an alias for `update` method in both Rails 4 and 5.

From `update` source for [Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L226) and for [Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L270), it takes one argument which is a `Hash` of the attributes.

As you are passing 2 arguments to the method which takes one argument Ruby is throwing an `ArgumentError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If there's a way to get things done without disturbing core functionalities of any library then it's better to go with that :) So that we don't have to worry about the maintenance.

Below is one such alternate approach.

```
class User
  before_save :process_password_attributes

  private

  def process_password_attributes
    return if changes[:password][1].present? || changes[:password_confirmation][1].present?
    restore_attributes(%i[password password_confirmation])
  end
end
```